# Alternative software for Hytera PD785G

Tags: software, radio-programming

I got a brand new [Hytera PD785G](http://www.hytera.com/navigation.htm?newsId=256&columnType=product&pageType=newDetail). When I turn it on, it says that it needs to be programmed. I've got a USB programmer cable and I know that there are official [drivers and software](http://www.hytera.com/productResources.htm?columnId=416&proId=256) for download.

Do I get most out of my radio using those drivers or is there some open source project which offers additional features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the official drivers and software. (I'd recommend that for any radio: that will let you know things are running.)

Some radios (Tytera MD-380, MD-390 and the clone Retevis R3, R8 and Zastone D900) have unlockable boot loaders and reverse-engineered firmware, but the Hytera PD785G is not in that group.